# AWS Oracle RDS: ORA-12560: TNS:Protocol adapter error

Tags: .net, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've moved my on premise **.NET MVC and WebAPI** application which uses **Oracle**, to AWS cloud. And with all things been equal, I just changed the connection string to reference **RDS Oracle**.

I have the following connection string in my Settings file:

```
<add key="OracleDatabaseConnectionString" value='Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=db-rds.uryrt6fhe.rds.amazonaws.com)(PORT=1526))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=db-rds)));' />
```

However, I am getting the following:

```
ORA-12560: TNS:Protocol adapter error
```

How do I solve this when using **RDS Oracle**, not on premise Oracle?

(in **Oracle SQL Developer**, I can successfully **connect**..so why not using the connection string above?)

Answer (score 0):

The error was definitely related to **opening a connection** to oracle rds instance (at one point I investigated DNS, LDAP, etc just to remove all variables).

This connection string only **works for on-premises oracle**.

```
<add key="UserLogin" value="User Id=prodabc;Password="pdw$7jhw@1;" />
<add key="OracleDatabase_onprem" value="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.2.2.87)(PORT=1526))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=oradb)));" />
```

And in my code I construct the connection to the database as follows:

```
var conn = Config.OracleDatabase_onprem;
var usr = Config.UserLogin;
OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(string.Format("{0}{1}",conn, usr)
```

And the following connection string **worked for oracle rds** and **worked for on-premises oracle**.

```
<add key="UserLogin" value="User Id=prodabc;Password=pdw$7jhw@1;" />
<add key="OracleDatabase_cloud" value="Data Source=db-rds.uryrt6fhe.rds.amazonaws.com:1526/oradb" />
```

And in my code I construct the connection to the database as follows:

```
var conn = Config.OracleDatabase_onprem;
var usr = Config.UserLogin;
OracleConnection oraConn = new OracleConnection(string.Format("{0}{1}",str, usr,conn)
```

**ONLY ON PREMISE**

```
"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.2.2.87)(PORT=1526))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=oradb)));User Id=prodabc;Password=pdw$7jhw@1;"
```

**ORACLE RDS AND ON PREMISE**

```
"User Id=prodabc;Password=pdw$7jhw@1;Data Source=db-rds.uryrt6fhe.rds.amazonaws.com:1526/oradb"
```